# Perl navigate through pages, alternative to Win32::Ole

Tags: perl

I have successfully been using Win32::Ole module to browser through pages and submit forms. This time I am trying something different. I want to open the browser, fill out form, click submit, and it will show an image from that page, then get that image saved in a folder. What is a useful module for this one to use? Since I don't know how to get the image from a page with Win32::Ole (I can get the contents if I navigate to that page, not when I submit a form and it goes to that page.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: WWW::Mechanize will allow you to navigate, click, fill forms, submit, etc.  I'm not sure about retrieving the image, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use WWW::Mechanize

from the [faq](http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize/FAQ.pod#How_do_I_save_an_image?_How_do_I_save_a_large_tarball?):

```
$mech->get( 'photo.jpg' );
$mech->save_content( '/path/to/my/directory/photo.jpg' );
```

Here's an example that retrieves and image (cats.gif) from a website and saves it to a local directory:

```
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new(autocheck =>1);
$mech->get( 'http://www.neurophys.wisc.edu/comp/cats.gif' );
$mech->save_content( 'c:/cats.gif' );
```

Comment: this is a good answer, but I can't use get because I have to submit to that page and not get the contents. Basically I submit a form, it pops an image

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries on CPAN for this.

WWW::Mechanize

WWW::Robot

CGI::Carp (with some trickery)

WWW::Selenium